# Can't connect Android app to Raspberry Pi to control GPIO

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to create an Android App to control a Raspberry PI GPIO. Both connected to the same network. I tried a static IP and a dynamic IP with port 80 forwarded. Still no success.
Here's the code i'm using ([Source](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Using-an-App/)):

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Switch swi = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.takE);
    swi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                new Background_get().execute("led1=1");
            }else{
                new Background_get().execute("led1=0");
            }
        }
    });

}
private class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.XXX.XXX/?" + params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

            in.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            return result.toString();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What happens when you open `http://192.168.XXX.XXX/?led1=1` in the browser on the phone or a computer on the same network ? If it doesn't work either, that means a problem with your network configuration or raspberry pi. Your code looks all right though.

Comment: what exception do you get? can your phone browser access that page? can your computer browser access it?

Comment: No I can't access the page on any browsers (phone and pc). What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use http but sockets to communicate.

Therefore you should create a ServerSocket on your Raspberry PI and a Socket on your android.
You can just follow the oracle Socket example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

To control the GPIOs i would recomend the use of http://pi4j.com/
I am using this library myself and i am very happy with it.

If you want to have multiple clients you should use `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` in a while loop and start a new thread for every client.

Comment: this does not answer the question.